# Site URL for Eclipse to Install org.apache.http library

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to use the apache http components in my application. I need to install it in Eclipse but I cannot find the proper URL for the site. From what I read I'm supposed to use 'https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi'. However, when I try that Eclipse gives me a no software found error. What is the correct URL for Eclipse? TIA.

Comment: There is not a special eclipse update site for the apache projects. That link is to directly download the jar yourself, then you can add that jar to your project. Alternatively, use maven (and m2e).

Comment: I did not know that. This is a maven project so I was able to find that dependency. Thanks.

Comment: There are Apache HttpComponents bundles in [Eclipse Orbit](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/), e. g. update site URL: `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20180606145124/repository/`